# mysql CURSOR - UNABLE TO ITERATE THROUGH THE RECORDS

Tags: mysql, cursor

THE CURSOR IS NOT GOING TO THE ELSE STATEMENT. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? HOW CAN I DEBUG IN MYSQL ?
I am trying to get the list of task Ids with null values and then for each taskID, I am calling  a SP to create start data and due date of the missing tasks(greater than the max(start_date available) until the current_date

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS zcursor_ADDTA1;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE zcursor_ADDTA1(
#out retCount int
)
BEGIN
  #DECLARE C_ID INT;
  DECLARE C_TASK_ID INT;
  DECLARE C_pattern varchar(100);
  DECLARE C_REM INT;
  DECLARE ACT_T_STTM VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE ACT_T_DTTM VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE TZ VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE T_STDT DATE;
  DECLARE T_EXDT DATE;
  DECLARE retCount INT;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE TA_MAX_ST_DT DATE;
  #DECLARE P1 INT;

  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR  SELECT  TASK_ID, PATTERN, reminder_days_before,  ACTUAL_TASK_START_TIME,ACTUAL_TASK_DUE_TIME,TIMEZONE,
  START_DT,EXP_DT FROM OCC_ML_TASK_RECURRENCE TR WHERE PATTERN = 'DAILY' AND CALENDAR_TYPE='' AND IS_CANCELED =0 AND EXP_DT>CURRENT_DATE();

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    SET retCount = 0;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH  NEXT FROM cursor_i INTO  C_TASK_ID,C_pattern,C_REM,ACT_T_STTM,ACT_T_DTTM,
    TZ,T_STDT,T_EXDT;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    ELSE
    SELECT MAX(TA.START_DTM)FROM 
    OCC_ML_TASK_ACTIVITY TA
    WHERE TA.TASK_ID=C_TASK_ID INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
    
    SELECT DATE_ADD(TA_MAX_ST_DT,INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
    
    WHILE (TA_MAX_ST_DT<=CURRENT_DATE())
        DO
        BEGIN 
          IF WEEKDAY(TA_MAX_ST_DT)=4 THEN
             CALL ZTA_MISSINGDATA_INSERT(C_TASK_ID ,TA_MAX_ST_DT);
             SELECT DATE_ADD(TA_MAX_ST_DT,INTERVAL 3 DAY)INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
          ELSEIF WEEKDAY(TA_MAX_ST_DT)=5 THEN
             #"NO INSERT "
             SELECT DATE_ADD(TA_MAX_ST_DT,INTERVAL 2 DAY)INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
          ELSEIF  WEEKDAY(TA_MAX_ST_DT)=6 THEN
        #"NO INSERT "
             SELECT DATE_ADD(TA_MAX_ST_DT,INTERVAL 1 DAY)INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
          ELSE
             CALL ZTA_MISSINGDATA_INSERT(C_TASK_ID ,TA_MAX_ST_DT);
             SELECT DATE_ADD(TA_MAX_ST_DT,INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO TA_MAX_ST_DT;
          END IF;
        
        END;
    END WHILE;
    END IF;
    
    

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;

END;
;;
```

Comment: Check that none SELECT statement in LOOP body returns zero rows - this will cause your handler firing. Try to add `SET done := FALSE;` immediately before `FETCH`.

Comment: *HOW CAN I DEBUG IN MYSQL ?* Create service `log` table (`CREATE TABLE log(record TEXT);`). Add INSERT statements which saves the values of intermediate variables and unique self number into this service table (`INSERT INTO log CONCAT('Point:', 123, ', var1=', var1, ', var2=', var2, ...);`). Execute the procedure then investigate the table content, retrieve execution flow and variables values change.

Comment: Does your SP exit or is it in an infinite loop?

Comment: it exits after the 'if done ' clause